# Blockstack-Radiks: Missing signing keys

Tags: blockstack

I am adding Radiks to my blockstack project. When saving the first model I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object."
    fromObject index.js:311
    from index.js:137
    from index.js:149
    getPublicKeyFromPrivate keys.js:25
    signECDSA ec.js:139
    sign model.js:249
    save model.js:157
```

It looks like that a userGroupKey is missing. Where do I need to specify it? The configuration is just a fake radiks server url. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have at least a local radiks server running.

The issue for me was that I didn't call `User.createWithCurrentUser` on each page. I did on the login page when `handlingPendingSignIn` but I didn't on pages when the user was already signed in (after `isUserSignedIn`). Adding `User.createWithCurrentUser` on these pages solved the problem.